# VBScript using variables value

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run a VBScript which opens a program with elevated privileges and also pass it parameters.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim path = "app.exe"
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
    path = path & WScript.Arguments(0)
End If
oShell.ShellExecute path, , , "runas", 1
```

I get an error in the 2nd line. I tried using `As String` but that also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the actual error msg, that helps a lot when you ask for help here at SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to declare a variable and set a value at the same time. Try this syntax instead.

```
Dim path
path = "app.exe"
```

or alternatively:

```
Dim path : path = "app.exe"
```

Where is the object `WScript` coming from? I don't see it initialized.

A great 'feature' to turn on is `Option Explicit`. When activated you must explicitly declare all variables by using the `Dim` or `ReDim` statements. If you try to use an undeclared variable name, an error occurs at compile time. This makes it easier to spot problems.

Comment: `WScript` is a builtin object (of `wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`).